# Mexican style taco cheese

Tags: cheese, seasoning

So I know these cheeses are a blend of yellow and white cheddar as well as some Monterey Jack (sometimes pepper jack), but do you know what seasonings are used to make these taco style shredded cheese blends?

I am guessing cumin and chili powder, but if anyone knows for sure that would be great in order to duplicate when recipes call for these shredded blends.

Comment: Do you mean products like [this](https://www.sargento.com/our-cheese/shredded-cheese/off-the-block-fine-cut/sargento-fine-cut-shredded-4-cheese-mexican)? Can you please be more specific what you mean by "taco style shredded cheese blends"?

Comment: Well I meant to keep it rather generic on purpose, but yeah something like that, but as I said above, I am looking for what seasonings are used in the seasoned blends. What you picked isn't a seasoned cheese blend, it's just a 4 cheese blend.

Comment: I've never seen a "seasoned" version of "taco cheese"... so that's why I'm trying to get more information. I see taco **meat** seasoning all the time but cheese is usually simply... cheese.

Comment: Seriously? That's very surprising, it would be on the shelf or rack right next to what you showed. Here are links to two examples, also sargento. https://www.sargento.com/our-cheese/shredded-cheese/chef-blends/sargento-chef-blends-shredded-nacho-taco-cheese.   And.   https://www.sargento.com/our-cheese/shredded-cheese/chef-blends/sargento-chef-blends-shredded-taco-cheese

Comment: Ah. Hmmm... I don't really buy pre-shredded cheese, so that may be the problem. It's not a section of the store I visit.

Comment: Well normally we don't either, hence the question. :-) I like to make things from scratch, sometimes that also includes simple cheeses. I make my own marscapone for example.

Comment: I have to go to the store later... maybe I'll go and see what's on the back of the label... seeing as they've opted not to include the ingredients panel.

Comment: Here's the ingredient list from the taco blend. Found it on EWG. From the Package
CHEDDAR, COLBY AND OTHER NATURAL CHEESE [PASTEURIZED MILK, CHEESE CULTURE, SALT, ENZYMES, ANNATTO (VEGETABLE COLOR)], MONTEREY JACK AND MANCHEGO CHEESE (PASTEURIZED MILK, CHEESE CULTURE, SALT, ENZYMES), TACO SEASONING (MALTODEXTRIN, CHILI PEPPER AND OTHER SPICES, SALT, SUGAR, POTATO FLOUR, ONION POWDER, GARLIC POWDER, OLEORESIN PAPRIKA), POTATO STARCH AND POWDERED CELLULOSE (TO PREVENT CAKING), NATAMYCIN (A NATURAL MOLD INHIBITOR).

Comment: Thanks Cindy, so it looks like my homemade recipe may include chili powder, paprika, garlic powder, onion powder. And probably cumin/coriander are "the other spices" since those two are often what makes a dish taste "Mexican inspired" if you know the flavor profile I am talking about.

Comment: So, maybe it's because I'm in Texas but this product is not in my grocery store! Guess that's why I've never seen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do a fajita night once a week in my house; so I have tuned the following recipes over the last 10 years or so.

```
1/2 tsp of each:
ground cumin
onion powder
salt
chili powder
cornstarch (ONLY if melting cheese)
crushed red peppers (optional for spicy)
garlic powder
oregano leaves
(Heavy cream and butter if melting)
```

Cheese base is pending my mood; queso fresca, standard white sauce with cheddar or some fancy mexican blend with the standard, colby/cheddar/jack...

Based on your post i would recommend the colby/cheddar/jack with spices (can we call that the fajita trinity?).

Comment: How much cheese do you use for that amount of spices

Comment: hmm; well they are alot of variables; who you are cooking for; what type of cheese, what is it going on (steak, carnita, chicken?).  Adding cream and melting?  Good starting point is 2 cups of cheese with above, and modify based on taste.